# How to pass multiple parameter to a Route from controller in Laravel ? (Integer & Varchar)

Tags: laravel, controller

This is my controller function return:

```
return redirect(route('adviceinput', $patient_id, $prescriptionID));
```

This is my **`web.php`**:

```
Route::get('/advice-input/{id}/{pres_id}', [PrescriptionController::class, 'adviceInput'])->name('adviceinput');
```

Is this the right way to pass multiple parameter?

This is give me an error like:

Missing required parameters for [Route: adviceinput] [URI: advice-input/{id}/{pres_id}]

Answer (score 0):

It is a pretty good idea to use an associative array where the key is the route parameter name:

```
return redirect()->route('adviceinput', [
    'id' => $patient_id,
    'pres_id' => $prescriptionID,
]);
```

You will have to make sure neither of these variables is `null`, empty, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in this way :

```
return redirect(route('adviceinput', ['id' => $patient_id, 'pres_id' => $prescriptionID]));
```

Comment: @ParvezHossain please mark it accepted, if it helped

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
return redirect()->route('adviceinput', [
    'id' => $patient_id, 
    'pres_id' => $prescriptionID
]);
```